# How can I control grunt-contrib-cssmin sourcemap URLs?

Tags: gruntjs, source-maps, grunt-contrib-cssmin

I am trying to configure my Gruntfile to auto-generate sourcemaps for my CSS files. I have several unminified CSS files which I combine into one minified file, but I would like to reference the unminified files for debugging in `dist/src/_assets/css/` via the sourcemap. I am using grunt-contrib-cssmin version 0.14.0 and grunt 0.4.5.

My goal project structure is roughly:

- dist

  - _assets

    - css
  - src

    - _assets

      - css
- src

  - _assets

    - css

My grunt-contrib-cssmin config is:

```
        cssmin: {
            options: {
                keepSpecialComments: false,
                sourceMap: true
            },
            build: {
                files: {
                    'dist/_assets/css/portfolio.css': [
                        'src/_assets/css/bootstrap.css',
                        'src/_assets/css/font-awesome.css',
                        'src/_assets/css/portfolio.css'
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
```

I have a separate copy task that copies **bootstrap.css**, **font-awesome.css**, and **portfolio.css** to `dist/src/_assets/css`, but for some reason, the sourcemap is trying to reference `dist/_assets/css/src/_assets/css/` instead of `dist/src/_assets/css`. Is there any way I can modify the directory the sourcemap is looking at without having to modify the sourcemap manually? This is pretty confusing to me because essentially the same settings in grunt-contrib-uglify do exactly what I want regarding sourcemaps (i.e. they reference `dist/src/_assets/js`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I gave up on trying to configure the sourcemap paths directly in `grunt-contrib-cssmin` and just used [grunt-text-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-text-replace) to get my paths squared away:

```
replace: {
    build: {
        src: 'dist/_assets/css/portfolio.css.map',
        dest: 'dist/_assets/css/',
        replacements: [
            {
                from: 'src/_assets/css/',
                to: '../../../src/_assets/css/'
            }
        ]
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

grunt-contrib-cssmin do not provide any sourcemap path option like feature til now. I recommend to use the cssmin only for production not for development.

"csswring" by the Kyo Nagashima might be the solution for your problem...